# Password protected zip file wont output correctly?

Tags: python, zip, txt, read-write

I am using Python to create a list of groups. It only makes sense to me that, using the code, I have for creating the password protected zip, I can create the input in my code as long as it is created before listing the input. As such, I have created a txt file which then needs to be placed in a password protected zip. With the code I am using below, I get this error message when I try to run it: (OSError: error in opening /Users/name/Desktop/Groups.txt for reading). I'm simply not very experienced in this regard and wouldn't know how to solve this issue (+ I am extremely desperate right now). This is the code I have so far, but it does not work:

```
#creates .txt file to put in zip folder
with open("Groups.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write("Each row is a group:" + '\n')
    for row in final_group:
        s = ", ".join(map(str, row))
        file.write(s+'\n')

# creates password protected zip
inpt = "/Users/name/Desktop/Groups.txt"
pre = None
oupt = "/Users/name/Desktop/Groups.zip"
password = "password"
com_lvl = 5
pyminizip.compress(inpt, None, oupt, password, com_lvl)
```

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: On which line are you getting this issue?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I am getting it on the last line (when the actual compression is supposed to occur).

Comment: Try setting `inpt = "Groups.txt"`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur It worked and I can't believe I hadn't tried that yet, thank you so so much :)

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input file might be in a different directory, because of which there's an error.  You can either

1. Set `inpt = "Groups.txt"`
2. Set `with open("/Users/name/Desktop/Groups.txt", 'w') as file:`